# How to use Google Maps Android API by Google Play Services 11 on an Emulator with Android 8

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-8.0-oreo

I want to run my Google Maps Application on an Android 8 Emulator.
As Google is suggesting, one should use the Google Maps Android API provided by the Google Play Services in the Version 11.

For this I put `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'`
in my gradle file.

When I start my emulator with android 8 its only providing google play services with version 10.9.30 and the map is not showing up.

I'm running the emulator with android studio 2.3.3 on Mac.

How can I get my Google Play Services to version 11 updated in order to use Google Maps Android API?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you mean that you've put that line in the gradle file, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. I already made it to work.. but I used Android Studio 3.0 Preview Version to update my emulator.

Comment: Please post the stack trace, if something is not shown here must be wrote why it didin't

Comment: Which stack trace should I post? I just installed Android Studio 3.0 Preview and this automatically updated the google play services to 11.0.55. And then also `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'`in the apps gradle file works - and the map is shown.

Comment: As stack trace I intend the output of the android monitor file.

Comment: I know what you mean.. but there was no stack trace.. the app did not crash - it just showed that the version of the google play services is not up to date.

Comment: Same problem over here. App does not crash but map view says: "App won't run unless you update Google Play services". Tried with Android Studio 2.3.3, play services 11.0.0 and every available Google API emulator.

Comment: I cannot confirm that updating to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3 and Android Emulator revision 26.1.1 worked for me. Still same error.

Comment: I've gone through the same problem recently (trying out Firebase where latest version is also 11.0.0) and did some digging, but unfortunately, it seems that an emulator image with a GPS v11 isn't available yet. You'll either have to downgrade to a lower maps library version that matches the emulator's version of GPS or you test it with an actual device with the corresponding version OR you could try sideloading the latest GPS APK to the emulator (although I haven't tried this one though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my emulator with Android Studio 3.0 Preview. As you can see in the screenshot the Google Play Services is updated to version 11.0.55.

And also my grade file with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'` is working now.

Further I'm using `compileSdkVersion 26` and `buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"`

[image: App information of Google Play Services]

Also see my settings for my SDK Platforms and SDK Tools:
[image: SDK Platform]
[image: SDK Tools]

Comment: Hi Marcel. Is this an actual answer or was it supposed to be an update to your question?

Comment: Hey AL. for my case this is an actual answer for my question. But it would be nice if somebody could confirm that it is also working for him.

Comment: Whoooaaa.. Cool. I'd guess I'll double check on my side. For some reason there isn't any GPS v11 showing up. Thanks!