# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I've seen this question asked and replies along the lines of re-syncing the project and updating the `SDK`.  I am right at the beginning of a new project and trying to set up authentication with `firebase` and I'm getting the following errors

Does android studio just hate me?

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0 Open
>   File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog
>       Error:Error:line (29)Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0 Show in
>   File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

Comment: did you set classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' in project gradle and apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44499458/4625829

Answer (score 10):

Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager click on SDK Tools and update the following:

- **Google Repository**
- **Android SDK Platform-Tools**

Comment: upvoting affirmative ;)

Comment: I have updated both of those and yet I still get same error as OP.

Answer (score 4):

Just goto sdk manager and update google repository.

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Comment: Please Mark answer as correct to thank anyone.happy coding.

Comment: Sorry, such a newbie

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLZba.png)

you can only click on AddAnalytics to your app
 follow 
   this https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by using 10.0.0

Thanks all for your help

Nick

Comment: I've just tried to compile with firebase 11.2 as it was written on their website (today) but it couldn't resolve for it as well so I lowered the firebase version to 11 and it worked =)

Answer (score 0):

for android studio 4.1.2.

1. first make sure you have installed google play services from SDK  manager. Go to Tools on the menu of android studio - SDK manager - SDK Tools if its not installed install it.
2. connect your app to firebase. On Tools click on firebase, firebase will open a new window, click on analytics. it will direct you to firebase site, from there create a project, it will automatically select your project.
   3.when you go back to your project you will see "connected to firebase"
   4.so if you run your project and get the error-  could not find com. google. firebase 19.3.1
   paste this to your project/ build.gradle
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5' on the dependencies- DONT FORGET TO SYNC NOW
   Then on the app/build.gradle at the bottom/end of the file paste this
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   5.Rebuild your project and the run again.

NB/classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

if it was helpful leave a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your project level build.gradle file have these:

```
 allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'  }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

lines order is very importance for the Gradle.

1)
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.20'

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'//3.2.0
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.4'
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}
```

and

2)

```
dependencies {
compile project(':libraries')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//--------------------------------- One Signal-------------------
//compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.1.1, 3.3.99]'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
//-------------------------------------------------------------
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

good luck